# Why we think that we thinking by ourselves, independent and free

Tags: consciousness, free-will, reality, creationism

If anything thats every been created depends on its creator. Take computers for example where they think math but its us that programmed them.

*Then why do we feel that we think by ourselves,* is it just a over glorification of self being that we term as **consciousness** ?
 If tomorrow a computer is programmed to conclude that it learns and thinks by itself, then what is the *difference* between computer and human?

Why do we think that we are different and unique (if everything depends on its source)?
   Is it a deliberate feeling/program incorporated by our creator to create a illusion? If yes what is the purpose of this illusion?

Comment: there are many beliefs in your question: that we exist as separate entities. that there is a creator . that we were created. that we all think that way.

Comment: This is a very broad question, which seems to incorporate an number of "big questions", what is consciousness, are humans special, is free will an illusion, what is the meaning of life etc...

Comment: We are the creator. You just did not discover it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question rest on some nebulous assumptions, so lets address them first:

> Anything that's ever been created depends on it's creator.

The problem with that statement is two-fold.

First - and I think this is a nice illustration of the importance of semantics - the word `depends` is  misleading.  For instance, I *depend* on my legs to walk, and walking (ignoring artificial means here) *depends* on legs, but neither walking or legs *depend* on the fact that long ago something created them (ignoring here that existence of legs depend on the creator or origin - that is not the point).

So *depends* is a tricky word.  But I think you are intending to have depends mean something like **exists within the confines and context created by the creator**.  That's an acceptable use of the word *depends* for the purposes of the question.  But that assumption has a problem.  It implies that it is known that humans (for that matter anything) are limited by barriers that exist within them from their creation.  That is to say; it implies that nothing can be created that can itself create; and can create beyond the bounds of the limitations imposed by their creator.  (I won't debate now whether or not anything can - I'm just pointing out here that the implication is neither proven nor generally accepted).

> If tomorrow a computer is programmed to conclude that it learns and thinks by itself, then what is the difference between computer and human?

Again, here you are implying something unstated.  Disregarding the nagging issues of the human being and *SELF* in general - you are still presupposing something.  If the computer is programmed to conclude that it learns by itself, then it will conclude it learns by itself, and whatever comes from that will come.  However, what a computer concludes or not is irrelevant here, and furthermore does not prove that our experience of learning is just something that we concluded, and not actual learning.

Now; you keep talking about our creator.  But I want to know who that is.  Is it intended to be God (and for that matter - is it God with a white beard and a throne)?  If it is, then you might wish to enter into a debate over whether or not He is the source of us - or in what manner He is the source of us.  Without that assumption distinguished, the rest of this makes no sense.

Is our creator the seemingly focused - but random - process of natural selection and evolution?  Our thoughts are a byproduct of that - for sure - but there is no definitive conclusion within the scientific community as to the what is at the source of consciousness, let alone where our thoughts come from.  Also, given that evolution is not a thing, but a world loosely draped over millions and billions of subtle transformations; in the instance that you were referring to evolution, it is hard to pinpoint a *creator* at all.

See, I think the real question you should be asking is, "Where does this thing I call my **SELF** come from?  And though I know there is no one permanent thing that can be called my **SELF**; why do I have the overwhelming, unshakable illusion that I am a thing in a skin sack standing on a dirt ball looking through two eye-holes; and why am I at best, only capable of describing the world out there with my words?  Why do I experience the limitations of my experience to be truths instead of nebulous illusions?

Only after the real questions get asked can we talk about the paradoxical nature of a structure that doesn't exist, yet creates itself and believes it is the structure that it has created.

Comment: Nice answer but if we go deep down to that singularity of dependency, then can 1 come from 0 without something? Or may we are surrounded by physical laws which clearly says no we can't.

Comment: What makes you think a. `0` ever existed? or b. (assuming it did) that the something that created `1` acted like an engineer and not just like a billiard ball striking another?  (In the second case, the influence is accidental and not tied to the design structure;nor would it be able to impose limitations per se).

Comment: Oh, and if `0` ever existed, then `1` couldn't exist, because `0` wouldn't include it.  If the one beyond `0` existed, then `0` is not `0` at all, but merely an empty space next to `1`

Comment: Your argument for existence of 1 seems good, but the fact that you presume that its accidental don't. Bcoz why everything around us seems so perfect (sun, weather, physics laws). I don't conclude that their is some engineer behind bcoz he too will need some1 to create him.  Another interesting part I feel is doing an experiment on Human (keep a human in some place not earth) and then bring back to test how he reacts on good, bad , tastes? Of course its not possible to do real test, but that would be amazing to test the actual genesis of Human Mind, Brain N testing that untaught consciousness

Comment: I find it difficult to parse your response.

Comment: I can rephrase OP question for you in real form : "How do I think? How do my ideas come to me? Where do my creations come from?" "Can i think/create everything as easy as i walk?". Simple as that.

Comment: Which question?  The comment or the original?

Answer (score -1):

Look, user1167442 discusses more on humans abilities, so I will focus on a computers' **Inability**. The reason computers and humans are different is that a human mind has one thing no prorammer will be able to create (at least at this point in time) and that is creativity. You can not teach creativty.

A computer can learn only what you teach it, and proramming it to extrapolate concepts like humans can, would be very difficult. A computer will always be limited to a library, while a human being even at a young age is able to Create Art. If you could find a single computer program that could paint art and eventually improve itself indetically to a child going through Grades 1,2 and 3 all the way to secondary school- you would have found the basis for AI(That is, your program has managed to "inspire" data which reflects personal emotions).

That brings me to my second point. You can not teach emotions. You can only experience them and then will often link the word used for that emotion to the psycological and phsical experiences you had during the situation you went through. Meanwhile, since it is working on a series of programmed chips whic define its actions, when faced with a situation where it should express an emotion, (A new upgrade!) it would simply interpret the data and respond with a series of written down commands.

Look, in the futures, where computers become much better, and so can what programmers can do with them, there will be amazing achievements (and who knows there may even be an AI), but to make a computer that can be compared to a human will always be impossible. Humans spend time asking phylosophical questions like "*what is the meaning of my life*?" Meanwhile computers would interperet that as "***Irrelevent Data***"(Ironically).

Remember this and you may realise the answer to the question you seek.

Mona.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is vague and makes several false assumptions.

First, let's start with the idea that we have a creator. This is false. Human beings evolved by natural selection.

Second, you say "why do we feel that we think by ourselves" without saying what would be required for actually thinking by yourself.

Third, if "thinking by yourself" means creating new explanatory knowledge, then people do create new explanatory knowledge so the whole premise of your question is false.

Fourth, nobody currently knows how to program a computer to create new knowledge but you offered no argument against it being possible and there are explanations that imply it is possible. The theory of computation explains that any finite physical system can be simulated by a computer operating using finite resources. We are physical systems and we can create knowledge so it is possible for a computer to be programmed to create knowledge.